# How to change the Workflow approval submitter from apex code in test class?

Tags: apex, approval-process

I have an approval process for which the  intial submitter  who creates the opportunity is to be 'Raj'. When I write the test class for it I assign the  opportunity owner using a soql query

op.owner = [SELECT Name FROM User where name = 'Raj' and isActive = true];

On running the test class it is printing that opportunity owner is assigned as Raj in debug log. But when it is checking with the approval process. It is showing the intial submitter as me. I dunno how to change the initial submitter for this approval process in apex test class.

Any Help is much appreciated!

Thank you,
Prasanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you've not provided your test class, it sounds like you're using `seeAllData = true`. If you've not specified a `RunAs` user, whomever is running the unit test will likely be the user that is shown as the one who submitted it for approval. If you want a specific user to do the submission, then you'll want to specify them as the `RunAs` User for the Unit Test. It's best to create those users within your test class so you'll have control over them and repeatability. You'll also be able to assert them in your results.